# facing issue with encrypted password with login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when I login with the encrypted password functionality then login not work and when I login without the encrypted password functionality then login work fine

HomeController.cs

```
        public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] hashBytes = ComputeHash(clearText);
                byte[] saltBytes = GetRandomSalt();
                byte[] saltHash = ComputeHash(saltBytes.ToString());

                byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = new byte[hashBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
                    hashWithSaltBytes[i] = hashBytes[i];
                for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
                    hashWithSaltBytes[hashBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];

                string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashWithSaltBytes);

                return hashValue;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        //random salt generation
        public static byte[] GetRandomSalt()
        {
            int minSaltSize = 16;
            int maxSaltSize = 32;

            Random random = new Random();
            int saltSize = random.Next(minSaltSize, maxSaltSize);
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);
            return saltBytes;
        }
        // hashing
        public static byte[] ComputeHash(string plainText)
        {
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA256Managed();
            return hash.ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);
        }

        public ActionResult create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult create(student stud)
        {

            string pass = Encrypt(stud.password);
            stud.password = pass;        //here assigning a string pass to stud.pass

            var create = dbstud.students.Add(stud);
            dbstud.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Login");

        }

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(student stud)
        {
            var login = dbstud.students.Where(x => x.username == stud.username && x.password == stud.password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (login != null)
            {
                Session["username"] = login.username.ToString();
                Session["password"] = login.password.ToString();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
```

Login.cshtml

```
@model DemoFFI.Models.student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.username)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username)<br />

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.password)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.password)<br />

    <input type="submit" />
}
@Html.ActionLink("Create a New Registration", "Create")
```

**when I comment this code then login functionality work fine but password not store encrypted format**

```
            string pass = Encrypt(stud.password);
            stud.password = pass;        //here assigning a string pass to stud.pass
```

**when I uncomment this code then login functionality not work but password store encrypted format**

```
            string pass = Encrypt(stud.password);
            stud.password = pass;        //here assigning a string pass to stud.pass
```

I add this line in login functionality

```
if (login != null)
            {
                login.password = Encrypt(stud.password);

                Session["username"] = login.username.ToString();  //I add this line
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model DemoFFI.Models.student

<h2>Index</h2>

@if (Session["username"] != null)
{
    <text>Welcome <strong>@Session["username"].ToString()</strong></text>
}

<p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout")

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.firstname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.lastname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.username)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.studid })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
@{ Html.RenderAction("BlogCreate", "Home"); }
```

here give an error:

```
<td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.studid }) //**here give an eror object referance not set to an object**
</td>
```

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have saved encrypted password in DB, In the WHERE condition where you are checking username and password, the password is not encrypted. 
You need to encrypt the password entered by user before passing it to WHERE condition.

In your login post action

```
string pass = Encrypt(stud.password);
var login = dbstud.students.Where(x => x.username == stud.username && x.password == pass ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This could be because, your encryption is always producing different result, because of a random hash. You need to workout a way to encrypt in such a way that it should return the same result.

Comment: @S Sachin Vishwakarma ok I will try?

Comment: can you give any solution for that how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're not encrypting your password in your login action. If you store an encrypted password in your database, you also have to encrypt the password in your login action. Otherwise you won't be able to retrieve the matching record.

Comment: here I trying ```login.password = Encrypt(stud.password);``` but here give an error ```@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.studid })```  object referance not set to an object